# I have worked on Selenium And now i am working on Testcomplete, BUt i feel Playback in TestComplete is very slow, How to Increase it ???Any idea

Tags: selenium, testcomplete

I have Earlier worked on Selenium Webdriver -java -Eclipse for a long time, but now i have been working on testcomplete-9-vbscript,
I have though realised that the playback in selenium -eclipse was much faster tah twhat i have seen in test complete
My question is :-
Is there a particular way that we can optimise the playback time of testcomplete

Answer (score 0):

Below Points may Help you-

1) Please Confirm whether you are using Recorded Script for execution Or you are writing your own Scripts .Difference between it is, Script Prepared by Recorder, Collects all the Events and Objects based on your Activities performed while Recording ( May be some of them are not required during execution, and unnecessarily it makes delays , waits in your execution.

instead if you will drive your script by writing on your own code, then it may reduce your execution time.

2.) Modularization in Framework also reduces execution timing.( cause it makes Branching in code,Re-usability in Subroutines also minimizes timing.

3) You can add only those check points which are actually important during your Script Execution.

4) As an feature, Test Complete Collects some Browser Specific obj's and Properties also where as in case of Selenium , The RC/ Webdriver -Server directly recognizes your Code.

5) Also you can write Dynamic Waiting Conditions by using Looping, That can also improve your script performance.

You can Refer Support blogs for Framework Optimization,

- Please Correct me if i Mentioned anything Wrong., Thanks.